# Checking whether two values are isomorphic in Swift

Tags: performance, swift

Working through a book problem

> Write a function that accepts two values and returns true if they are isomorphic. That is, each part of the value must map to precisely one other, but that might be itself.
> Tip: Strings A and B are considered isomorphic if you can replace all instances of each letter with another. For example, “tort” and “pump” are isomorphic, because you can replace both Ts with a P, the O with a U, and the R with an M. For integers you compare individual digits, so 1231 and 4564 are isomorphic numbers. For arrays you compare elements, so [1, 2, 1] and [4, 8, 4] are isomorphic.

The author recommends casting both values to a string, then storing a dictionary that maps each character to the other character.

```
func challenge57(first firstValue: Any, second secondValue: Any) -> Bool {
    let first = String(describing: firstValue)
    let second = String(describing: secondValue)
    
    guard first.count == second.count else { return false }
    
    var characterMap = [Character: Character]()
    let firstArray = Array(first)
    let secondArray = Array(second)
    
    for (index, character) in firstArray.enumerated() {
        let correspondingCharacter = secondArray[index]
        
        if let currentMapping = characterMap[character] {
            if currentMapping != correspondingCharacter {
                return false
            }
        } else {
            if characterMap.values.contains(correspondingCharacter) {
                return false
            }
            
            characterMap[character] = correspondingCharacter
        }
    }
    
    return true
}
```

However, `contains()` is a linear time operation making the overall approach quadratic, and I’m struggling to come up with an optimization. Curious to hear any guidance in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

#### Review of your code

It may be a matter of personal taste, but I see `guard` as a language feature to avoid the “if-let pyramid of doom” or to check against exceptional situations, but not as a general replacement for a negated condition. In other works, I would write

```
guard first.count == second.count else { return false }
```

as

```
if first.count != second.count { return false }
```

You convert the strings to arrays first, which is a good idea if subscripting by character position is needed later, as in

```
let correspondingCharacter = secondArray[index]
```

But the characters from both strings are accessed sequentially, so one can enumerate the characters in parallel and save the additional array storage:

```
for (character, correspondingCharacter) in zip(first, second) { ... }
```

The time-consuming

```
if characterMap.values.contains(correspondingCharacter)
```

can be avoided if we keep a *set* of all characters seen in the second string to far. Inserting a character into the set and checking if it was already present can be done with a single call.

You also should choose a more descriptive function name.

The code would then look like this:

```
func isomorphic(first firstValue: Any, second secondValue: Any) -> Bool {
    let first = String(describing: firstValue)
    let second = String(describing: secondValue)
    
    if first.count != second.count { return false }

    // Map from characters in the first string to characters in the second string:
    var characterMap = [Character: Character]()
    // All characters seen in the second string so far:
    var seen = Set<Character>()
    
    for (firstChar, secondChar) in zip(first, second) {
        if let currentMapping = characterMap[firstChar] {
            if currentMapping != secondChar { return false }
        } else {
            if !seen.insert(secondChar).inserted { return false }
            characterMap[firstChar] = secondChar
        }
    }
    
    return true
}
```

I also (usually) prefer to put the statements in blocks on separate lines, e.g.

```
if first.count != second.count {
    return false
}
```

but that again is a matter of personal taste. One advantage during debugging is that you can more easily set a breakpoint on that statement.

#### Review of the problem description and the API

It makes sense to say that two strings are isomorphic if there is a one-to-one correspondence between their characters. It makes also sense for arrays if their respective elements can be compared for equality, i.e. if the array elements conform to the `Equatable` protocol.

More generally, “each part of the value must map to precisely one other” makes sense for *collections* (whose elements are comparable).

But it makes no sense (in my opinion) to define this kind of “isomorphy” for arbitrary values. Of course you can convert any value to a string with `String(describing:)`, but

- unless the values conform to `CustomStringConvertible` or a related protocol, the result is unspecified, and
- even if all values conform to `CustomStringConvertible`, the result may not be what one expects.

Examples demonstrating the second point:

- `challenge57(first: [11, 2], second: [3, 44])` evaluates to `false` even though the arrays are isomorphic, because their string representations are not isomorphic.
- `challenge57(first: [1, 2], second: ["1", "2"])` evaluates to `false`  even though each element of the first array can be uniquely mapped to an element of the second array.
- `challenge57(first: [], second: "12")` evaluates to `true` because the string representation of the empty array happens to be isomorphic to "12".

Therefore a better API in my opinion would be

```
func isomorphic<C1, C2>(first: C1, second: C2) -> Bool 
where C1: Collection, C1.Element: Equatable, C2: Collection, C2.Element: Equatable
```

The downside is that we can no longer use dictionaries and sets for faster lookup. But we can implement a *specialisation* for the case of hashable elements, and that would be not much different from the code above:

```
func isomorphic<C1, C2>(first: C1, second: C2) -> Bool 
where C1: Collection, C1.Element: Hashable, C2: Collection, C2.Element: Hashable {
    if first.count != second.count {
        return false
    }
    
    // Map from elements in the first collection to characters in the second collection:
    var map = [C1.Element: C2.Element]()
    // All elements seen in the second collection so far:
    var seen = Set<C2.Element>()
    
    for (firstElement, secondElement) in zip(first, second) {
        if let currentMapping = map[firstElement] {
            if currentMapping != secondElement { return false }
        } else {
            if !seen.insert(secondElement).inserted { return false }
            map[firstElement] = secondElement
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

This works as expected for strings and arrays:

```
print(isomorphic(first: "tort", second: "pump")) // true
print(isomorphic(first: "1234", second: 1234)) // Syntax error
print(isomorphic(first: [11, 2], second: [3, 44])) // true
print(isomorphic(first: [1, 2], second: ["1", "2"])) // true
```

Defining two *integers* to be isomorphic if there is a one-to-one correspondence between their decimal digits seems a bit arbitrary to me. (Why decimal digits and not the binary digits? What about negative numbers?). But if that is wanted then I would separate it as a function overload:

```
func isomorphic(first: Int, second: Int) -> Bool {
    return isomorphic(first: String(first), second: String(second))
}

print(isomorphic(first: 1231, second: 4564)) // true
```